# How to remove the [connect to metro to develop javascript in react native apps]

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am new to react native

The apps always show in real device
[connect to metro to develop javascript in react native apps]

How to remove it?

Is it disappeared in release?
[like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4a5TN.jpg)

Comment: Yes, it won't be visible in the production mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That message is gone when the app is built for release.

If you are developing your ReactNative app in something like [`expo`](https://docs.expo.io/) which uses Metro and have the App running on a Device, you can connect the app to your development environment to debug and make live code changes.

I'd suggest developing your app in the simulator first, then testing on a device later. You'll probably be able to work faster that way.